# Change Kotlin optional-like style

Tags: kotlin, optional

I have next method in client

```
fun authUser(loginRequest: LoginRequest): String?
```

I need to implement next logic: check if user already exists - nothing to do,
if user isn't existed - register him.

I wrote next

```
fun initTechUser() {
        when {
            client.authUser(USER_CREDENTIALS) == null -> {
                client.registerUser(MIGRATION_USER_CREDENTIALS)
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope there is practice to make this code better. Can somebody look at?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. For future reference, check [how to write a better question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)

Answer (score 2):

There's really no need to use a `when` statement for just one condition. A simple `if` will do just fine. Also, check your indentation.

```
fun initTechUser() {
    if (client.authUser(USER_CREDENTIALS) == null) {
        client.registerUser(MIGRATION_USER_CREDENTIALS)
    }
}
```

You could also extract an extra method to make the code more readable.

```
fun initTechUser() {
    if (!client.isAuthenticated()) {
        client.registerUser(MIGRATION_USER_CREDENTIALS)
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant is there way using java-Optional-style to implement such logic?

Comment: @ArtyomKarnov sure, there's always `fun initTechUser() { client.authUser(USER_CREDENTIALS)?.let { it.registerUser(MIGRATION_USER_CREDENTIALS } }` but I agree with @Simon Forsberg that extracting the `isAuthenticated()` method and using `if` is clearer/cleaner.